# Can you derive a Managed C++ class from an Unmanaged C++ class?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed-c++

I have an unmanged C++ class I have written in an unmanged dll.  I have a managed dll that references the unmanaged dll.  Can a class in the managed dll derive from the unmanaged class?

Using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Instances of managed classes are garbage collected and created on the CLR heap. Instances of unmanaged classes are allocated on the unmanaged heap. How could you be able to create an object whose data is partially on the managed heap and its base data on the unmanaged heap?

You should try other techniques, e.g. wrap a managed container over the unmanaged thing or vice versa and derive from that, probably.

Comment: AFAIK, objects, not classes, are allocated. And unmanaged objects can be allocated either in the stack or the heap.

You're right about wrapping the unmanaged object inside a managed object, though.

Comment: You are right about the terminology. However, I wanted to emphasis on how you declare your classes. That's why I used managed classes instead of managed objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *yet*.  Herb Sutter wrote an extensive [C++/CLI Design Rationale](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/C++CLIRationale.pdf) where he hints such things may indeed be possible one day.  However, it seems that Microsoft has stopped further development of C++/CLI?

Comment: 7 years later, and *"mixed types"* still haven't been introduced. I'm going to guess, that this won't ever make it. I don't know, whether Microsoft stopped development of C++/CLI. If they did, they also made sure that everything required is there. It is still the predominant solution to provide a managed interface to native implementations (outside of COM).

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is wrap you unmanaged class in a manager wrapper and then derive from that.